# push object to array in the javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to shorten or refactor this longVersion() function below? Any ideas is appreciated.
Thanks!

https://replit.com/talk/share/convert-obj-to-ary/137799

```
const person = {
  name: 'Juan De la Cruz',
  job: 'Programmer',
}

function longVersion(person) {
  let aryPerson = []
  if (Array.isArray(person) && person.length > 0) {
    aryPerson = person
  } else {
    aryPerson.push(person)
  }
  return aryPerson
}

const result = longVersion(person)
console.log('longVersion:', result)

//output: longVersion: [ { name: 'Juan De la Cruz', job: 'Programmer' } ]
```

Comment: So, if your input is an object, you want an array containing that object out, and if it's an array, you want just that array out?

Comment: Pretty sure this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links sir.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is convert the input to an array, if it isn't already an array, then this is enough:

```js
const person = { name: 'Juan De la Cruz', job: 'Programmer' };

function toArray(person) {
  return Array.isArray(person) ? person : [person];
}

const result = toArray(person);
console.log('toArray:', result);
```

Comment: Hmm, this is nice. Thanks